# Re-register Geofences in Android from a BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I spent hours but could not find an exact way to re - register geofences through a BroadcastReceiver. Re-registering requires the GoogleApiClient instance to be running in an activity and hence the app. Please help. Please tell me if wrong or provide a solution.

[Do Geofences remain active in android after a device reboot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20079906/do-geofences-remain-active-in-android-after-a-device-rebootot).

Answer (score 0):

First you need to have a GeofenceManager to handle all the persistence Geofence regions storage, you can persists your geofence region by saving each attribute on a preference key. After that you can implement a BroadcastReceiver to restore all your geofence regions from preferences.

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
public class GeofenceBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    GeofenceRegionsManager manager = new GeofenceRegionsManager(context);
    manager.restoreAllRegions();
  }
}
```

Should set permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

And set intent filter action android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED on AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: Thanks for replying.  I solved my problem though. Am starting a service in onReceive() and the service is taking take of the GoogleApiClient.

Comment: Please mention that "GeofenceRegionsManager" is a custom class. I ended up looking for documention on using GeofenceRegionsManager class, as it's not clear in your answer. Thanks!