# Re-register Geofences only when required

Tags: android, android-geofence

According to the [Android geofencing documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html#BestPractices) one should re-register the geofences if the following cases occur:

- The device is rebooted.

*Solution: The app should store the geofences internally (SharedPreferences) when the geofence is added. Then listen for the device's boot complete action, and re-register the stored geofences.*

- The app is uninstalled and re-installed.

*Solution: User should create the geofences again or store them remotely and then retrieve when the app opens for the first time.*

- The app's data is cleared.

*Solution: User should create the geofences again or store them remotely and then retrieve when the app opens for the first time.*

However, I don't know what to do in the following cases, please can you advice?

- Google Play services data is cleared. ***How can I detect this case?***
- The app has received a GEOFENCE_NOT_AVAILABLE alert. This typically happens after NLP (Android's Network Location Provider) is disabled. ***Not sure where this 'alert' is received***

Comment: Not sure where this 'alert' is received: It will be in you Service, where you will receive Transitions. Youcan check that using: GeofencingEvent geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);
        if(geofencingEvent.getErrorCode() == GeofenceStatusCodes.GEOFENCE_NOT_AVAILABLE)

Comment: Please see [my answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50869301/766755) as I believe it should cover all the cases where you should re-register geofences based on the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found no way of detecting the case of Google Play services data is cleared, so I just request for new geofences whenever the app is opened.

As @Sagar mentioned, GEOFENCE_NOT_AVAILABLE is received in the transitions service. This is received when the Location is disabled. To workaround this, I save the geofences (using SharedPreferences) whenever I request them, and then I have a BroadcastReceiver that detects when the Location is enabled again. I reload the saved geofences here.

Thanks.

Comment: LocationManager.PROVIDERS_CHANGED_ACTION will not work on API 26 and higher - What will you do now? :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48659124/locationmanager-providers-changed-action-will-not-work-on-api-26-and-higher